# Where should i include my modules in node.js and express?

Tags: node.js, backend

Im starting with backend web programming. Im using nodejs, express and mysql.
I started by making a app.js file with all my routes (where i included all the modules i needed) but now im trying to separate every route in a different .js file in "routes" folder and then use "app.use" in app.js file.

My question is, where should i include the modules? For example, in route "/show" i want to list all my current articles using a query to access the db. Should i include mysql module in the show.js file, in app.js file or in both?
Imagine that in show.js file, i want to import the function that has the query from another file. Which one of the three files should require "mysql" module?

Im also using .env file and i was wondering where should i include the dotenv module. In the main file, or in every file where i use the .env file?

thank you very much

Comment: You should require the module in the file(s), which use(s) the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several concepts of modules in nodejs that you may be missing.

**import or require are local to the module doing them**

When a module imports another module, the module entry points you imported are only available within that module.  This is not like a 1980s `<script>` tag in a browser where things that get defined within that imported script become globally available.  That's not how modules work in nodejs.  So, thus a module MUST import everything that it needs to use because nothing is globally available by default.

**Modules are cached by nodejs**

The above statement will undoubtedly lead to you importing the same utility module in many different modules because they all need to use it.  That is the correct way to do things.  The first time any module is loaded within a given nodejs execution, that module is cached so when subsequent other modules also attempt to load it, they are given the same module handle from memory. So, it's not inefficient to include the same module in many different modules.

**Modules should be as stand-alone as possible**

Consistent with the fact that a module should import everything that it needs to use itself, you want a module to be independently testable and perhaps even shareable without relying on some shared global environment.  This allows you to write test scripts that just load and exercise this specific module all by itself.  This is hugely beneficial for a project of any size and absolutely required as projects get larger with many developers.

---

Now, to your  specific questions:

> Which one of the three files should require "mysql" module?

Any module that needs to call mysql APIs directly should import the mysql module itself.  If it doesn't, it won't have access to the mysql APIs as those APIs are not global and should not be global.

Let's suppose you have module A which loads and calls module B which loads and calls the mysql module.  Module A only needs to import module B.  Module B needs to import mysql.

> Im also using .env file and i was wondering where should i include the dotenv module. In the main file, or in every file where i use the .env file?

In every file that calls a dotenv API.  Remember, there will really only be one instance of the dotenv module that will be shared by all who import the dotenv module.  But, each separate module that wishes to call a dotenv API must import it itself.  Otherwise, it won't have access to the APIs because those APIs are not global.